# Filter by timestamp in Query

Tags: django

I have a list of Jobs. They are filtered by job_type, and complete=False/True.
Ex: `Job.objects.filter(job_type=1, complete=False)`

How would I filter these by the timestamp of the Job like:
`job.timestamp.strftime(date_filter) == job.today().strftime(date_filter)`

So I want to return finaly a list like this:

```
Job.objects.filter(
   job_type=1,
   complete=False, 
   timestamp.strftime(date_filter)=datetime.today().strftime(date_filter)
).distinct()
```

Comment: I see i can use timestamp__year=etc , but what about timestamp__week ?

Comment: Its part of my template_tag, {% show_jobs "day" %} : that will then be date_filter = day = '%j'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you are trying to filter all of the Jobs that occur on a certain day?  So calculate a date range, and then use that in your filter:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today = datetime.now().date()

if date_filter == "day":
    timestamp_from = datetime.now().date()
    timestamp_to = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1)
elif date_filter == "month":
    # Etc...
elif date_filter == "year":
    # Etc...

Job.objects.filter(
    job_type = 1,
    complete = False, 
    timestamp__gte = timestamp_from,
    timestamp__lt = timestamp_to,
).distinct()
```

Otherwise, you might be able to do something funky using an [extra SQL WHERE clause](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)